# if exists update else insert mysql

Tags: mysql, sql-server, if-statement, sql-update, exists

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM two_player  WHERE title='math' and user2 is null)
 UPDATE two_player  SET score2='50' , user2='zahra' WHERE title='math' and user2 is null
 ELSE  
 INSERT INTO two_player  (user1,score1,title) values ('zahra', '50', 'math')
```

This query works right in sql server. But I am getting this error in the mysql:

> *#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM two_player WHERE title='math' and user2 is null) ' at line 1

why?!
what is the alternative for that?

Comment: yes, there is alternative. don't do logic in database layer

Comment: Very difficult to update sql server if existing in mysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Store Procedures to solve this problem like below

```
    DELIMITER $$
    DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `select_or_insert`$$
    CREATE PROCEDURE select_or_insert()
    begin

    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM test WHERE id="id") THEN
       SELECT * FROM test WHERE id="id";
    ELSE
       INSERT INTO test (id,name) VALUES ("id",'name');
    END if;

    END$$

   DELIMITER ;
```

and call it like this:

```
call select_or_insert();
```

Comment: Thank you! this query works right when I run it in the sql tab of phpMyAdmin. But when the mysqli_query() function in a php file performs this query I get this error:
 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER $$\n    DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `select_or_insert`$$\n    CREATE PROCED' at line 1

Comment: I do not have any idea about PHP, You can google how to call store procedure in php

Answer (score 0):

Use replace instead update or insert:-

```
REPLACE INTO two_player  (user1,user2,score1,score2,title) values ('zahra', 'zahra','50','50', 'math')
```

In this case you must have a unique index.

Else according to your programming language try this:-

```
UPDATE two_player  SET score2='50' , user2='zahra' WHERE title='math' and user2 is null

if updates_rows == 0:  
      INSERT INTO two_player  (user1,score1,title) values ('zahra', '50', 'math')
```

Comment: I am getting this error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'if updates_rows == 0: INSERT INTO two_player (user1,score1,title) valu' at line 3

Comment: i am providing sample to you, not quey

Comment: if updates_rows == 0:   will work in programming, what ever you are using.